# extracting an exe out of a downloaded zip in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, zip

When I try to extract an exe file out of a downloaded zip file, Windows 10 tells me in a popup:

> Windows found that this file is potentially harmful.
>
> To help protect your computer, Windows has blocked access to this file.

[image: Popup: Windows Security Warning]

I am not sure what the URL of the link is, but clicking on it redirects the browser to:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/products/windows?os=windows-10

(Well more precisely to the [German equivalent](https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/products/windows?os=windows-10) of that page.)

Given that I trust the source, how can I extract the file anyway?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because it's a pretty broad question as you don't have a lot of detail included. Both answers hint at that as well.

Comment: *Please* give me an upvote, now that I provided a screenshot and everything. I would like to improve the question even further but need some points for that.

Comment: You already improved it a lot but I doubt you'll gain a lot of points with this but don't worry as you have more questions and as you might be able to provide some answers on other questions you'll be able to gain them slowly. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what is actually causing that popup. Do you have Windows Defender or some other Anti Virus solution installed? Is it a popup from them? Are you sure you can trust the file? What options does the dialog give you?

One solution might to tell Windows to "Extract All" through the context menu.

Otherwise it might be sufficient to check the file properties and click unblock as the file might just be marked as a "internet file".

Comment: “Extract All...” deletes the zip and creates an empty folder. So it's actually worse. *Unblock* was the solution. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Details: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2015/08/19/blocked-access-to-files-with-windows-10/

Comment: You did quite a bit of research yourself but would you mind telling me which Windows 10 edition you're running? I haven't had that dialogue yet so I'm a bit curious if it could be because I'm running a "higher" edition.

Comment: I am using Windows 10 Pro. I guess you have the “Do not preserve zone information in file attachments” enabled as it says in the blog.

Comment: More details: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/883260

Comment: If it is, it's either because I rarely use IE to download (which usually sets the alternate data stream that marks a file as an internet file) or on Enterprise it's not enabled by default.

Comment: Note that file attachments in Skype for Business will also have the same security "features" that are mentioned in the article @Marcus linked

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple!
Right click on the compressed folder and view properties, then select 'Unblock' then apply.
This should solve any issues you had.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upload a screenshot of this message?

If it is an windows message with teh title "Windows protected your PC" you have an link "More info" and after you clicked on it you can make an exception for this file.

Comment: Now I attached a screenshot.

Comment: I have never seen this message or a warning like this, are your shure that your computer is free of malware? Specially that the link is just pointing to Windows 10 on microsoft and not an direct help. It could be that the malware wants to block you from using possible cleaning software.

Comment: You can try yourself, if you like. The file I was trying to unzip is: http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.24/chromedriver_win32.zip

Comment: Don't happen at my Windows 10...

Comment: This Microsoft blog reads “I found that by setting a Local Policy on the machine”. It’s called “Do not preserve zone information in file attachments”. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2015/08/19/blocked-access-to-files-with-windows-10/